# Error message after running sh run.sh, says 'Failed building wheel for h5py'

Tags: pip, h5py

I am trying to install the UseGalaxy genome analysis software.

I have run `sh run.sh` which runs fine until it comes to a error:

[end of output]

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build bx-python h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bx-python, h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have got HDF5 installed already.

I am a biologist, not a computer scientist - so please make your answers simple - thanks .

Python is installed, along with Homebrew

Full error message:

```
`  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bx-python
  Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [71 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py
      copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py
      copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py
      copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py
      copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_big_endian_file.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5o.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      copying h5py/tests/test_file_alignment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
      copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
      running build_ext
      Building h5py requires pkg-config unless the HDF5 path is explicitly specified using the environment variable HDF5_DIR. For more information and details, see https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#custom-installation
      error: pkg-config probably not installed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build bx-python h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bx-python, h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
```